# How to interpret strings containing `\###` (# being a digit)?

Tags: python-3.x, text

I have English text `'Slouchy Cable Knit Cardigan'` that need to translated to Spanish language. The Answer should be `'Cárdigan holgado de punto'`, but when python return this text from google api translated i got this `"C\303\241rdigan holgado de punto"`.

```
from google.cloud import translate_v3beta1 as translate

client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

project_id = ''
location = 'global'

parent = client.location_path(project_id, location)
response = client.translate_text(
    parent=parent,
    contents =['Slouchy Cable Knit Cardigan'],
    mime_type='text/plain',  # mime types: text/plain, text/html
    source_language_code='en',
    target_language_code='es')

print(response.translations)
```

---

```
Translated Text: translated_text: "C\303\241rdigan holgado de punto"
```

Is there a painless way to solve this problem?

Comment: This is most likely an encoding / decoding issue. I would recommend you to work out a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mcve) showing the issue. It is a much simpler starting point for people willing to help you. Also, perhaps you want to spell out `ESP`, there are a bunch of possible meaning for it in [computing alone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP#Computing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting is a binary representation of your data.

If `translated_text` is a Python `str`, it is likely using `latin1` encoding of a `utf-8` text.
Converting it to `bytes` and then back to `str` using the correct encoding should solve the issue:

```
text = 'C\303\241rdigan holgado de punto'
print(text)
# CÃ¡rdigan holgado de punto
print(text.encode('latin1').decode('utf8'))
# Cárdigan holgado de punto
```

(Unfortunately I cannot test your full code since I do not have valid Google API credentials -- and they are not available for free).

Answer (score 0):

Also one of solution will be use MessageToDict()

```
from google.cloud import translate_v3beta1 as translate
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict

client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

project_id = ''
location = 'global'

parent = client.location_path(project_id, location)
response = client.translate_text(
    parent=parent,
    contents =['Slouchy Cable Knit Cardigan'],
    mime_type='text/plain',  # mime types: text/plain, text/html
    source_language_code='en',
    target_language_code='es')

for translation in response.translations:
   print(MessageToDict(translation))
```

---

```
{'translatedText': 'Cárdigan holgado de punto'}
```